# Elasticsearch java client initialization fails

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm getting this error message while trying to run an application which connects to elasticsearch.

```
An attempt was made to call the method org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder;)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/path/application/target/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-5.6.3.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/RestHighLevelClient.class

It was loaded from the following location:

jar:file:/path/application/target/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-5.6.3.jar!/

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient
```

The application builds without errors and only one version of elasticsearch SDK exists in my maven repository.

This is the relevant portion of my pom:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This is the exception that I get while running the application:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'restHighLevelClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder;)V
```

This is how I'm initializing the RestHighLevelClient:

```
RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient
                .builder(new HttpHost(hostname, port, scheme));
builder.setMaxRetryTimeoutMillis(timeout);
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder.build());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring boot will try to autoconfigure elasticsearch which will internally use elastic 6 
    RestHighLevelClient(org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder builder) to create the elastic client. If you want to connect to an older version of elasticsearch please exclude elasticsearch autoconfiguration.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, RestClientAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: ElasticsearchRestHealthIndicator still fails - I had to disable it

Comment: Thanks. In my case, excluding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ElasticsearchRestClientAutoConfiguration.class}) ` works.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder;)
```

There is no constructor in `RestHighLevelClient` which takes `RestClientBuilder` as a parameter in `<version>5.6.3</version>`.

Did you try using version `<version>7.0.0-alpha1</version>` ?

Update:

Exception `An attempt was made to call the method org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<init>(Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder;`
tells that the code is it trying to execute a method that belongs to elasticsearch version 6.
In your case perhaps you have multiple version of Elasticsearch libs provided in run time, or your code might be complied by version 6, but in run time
the version 5 is provided.

Comment: I'm using <version>5.6.3</version> as the version of the underlying elasticsearch cluster is 5.6.3. But if version was the problem, it should not compile and throw an error right?

Comment: Indeed, only Elasticsearch version 6+ `org.Elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient` allows you to pass `org.Elasticsearch.client.RestClient` as a constructor parameter. Elasticsearch version 5 has no constructor like that.

Comment: According to these docs, it has such a constructor - https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/5.6.3/index.html

Comment: correction `org.Elasticsearch.client.RestClient` should be `org.Elasticsearch.clien.RestClientBuilder`

Comment: As I state in your doc https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/5.6.3/index.html there is no constructor to pass `org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder` into `RestHighLevelClient`

Comment: I'll clarify that as an edit to the question,but I'm not passing RestClientBuilder into a constructor of RestHighLevelClient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184745/discussion-between-varshavp27-and-dush).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference for configuration if you are using Spring Boot 2.3.x + Elasticsearch client 5.6.6, see if it helps. 
We recently upgraded Spring Boot to 2.3.3, while ELK is still on 5.6.6. The error was about Spring auto configuring ES `RestClient`, so another solution is to "configure it manually", and it can be used later somewhere else.

```java
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String esHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int esPort;
    
    @Value("${elasticsearch.prefix}")
    private String esPrefix;

    @Bean
    public RestClient lowLevelClient() {
        return RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(esHost, esPort, "http")).setPathPrefix(esPrefix)
                .setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder.setConnectTimeout(1000).setSocketTimeout(5000)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient() {
        return new RestHighLevelClient(this.lowLevelClient());
    }

// ------ before upgrade
//  @Bean
//  public RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient() {
//      RestClient rc = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(esHost, esPort, "http")).setPathPrefix(esPrefix)
//      .setRequestConfigCallback(builder -> builder.setConnectTimeout(1000).setSocketTimeout(5000)).build();
//      return new RestHighLevelClient(rc);
//  }
}
```

pom:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>
<!-- ..................  -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```